# What's the point of workers when things can inherently run in parellel?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the following two methods:

```
async function test1() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        let p = new Promise((resolve)=> {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("Thread 1 ", i);
                resolve();
            }, 5000, i);
        });
        await p;
    }
}
async function test2() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        let p = new Promise((resolve)=> {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("Thread 2 ", i);
                resolve();
            }, 1000, i);
        });
        await p;
    }
}
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve)=> {
    test1();
    resolve();
})
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve)=> {
    test2();
    resolve();
})
```

both `test1` and `test2` run at the same time yielding the following output:

```
Thread 2  0
Thread 2  1
Thread 2  2
Thread 2  3
Thread 1  0
Thread 2  4
Thread 2  5
```

This actually means that no `Manual Threading` would be needed to handle parallelism as in this situation in Nodejs. However, I have seen people using the `Worker` to implement multithreading and I cannot really understand the point behind that although I did Google and YouTube it before posting this question in SO.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything. Try to let both functions busy-loop for a while and the result will be different.

Comment: @tkausl , yes this code doesn't do anything special but a long running task. Would it make any difference if instead of the simple wait, I queried something from a big database? and would that block the second test method?

Comment: The point of real workers is, that you can actually use several cores at the same time, and have OS thread scheduling take place...

Comment: @ASDFGerte , assuming that you were about to write a socket that is meant to handle concurrent connections, in that case would the worker make any sense?

Comment: `setTimeout()` is not *"a long running task"*. It is a long "do nothing".

Answer (score -1):

What you can do in javascript is basically cooperative multitasking in a single thread. However some limitations apply:

1. It's only cooperative multitasking.
2. It's only single-threaded.

So while you can do `await Promise.all([foo(), bar()])` the only points when the execution may switch from `foo` to `bar` and the other way around are the `await`s. So having this code:

```
async function foo() {
  doFirst();
  doSecond();
  await doThird();
}
```

code from `bar()` can only run before the functions run, during the `await`, and after the function finished. It will *never run between doFirst()`and`doSecond()`.

Next all runs in one thread. And this thread can only do a single thing at a time. So having non-coperative code will hold the entire JS thread:

```
function busyWait(ms) {
    const target = ms + (new Date()).getTime();
    while(true) {
      if((new Date()).getTime() > target) {
        return;
      }
    }
}
```

This will block all other code while running. However only a single CPU core will be used.